# Calling an SQL Connection method in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, class, methods

I am calling this method to my Login Form. I don't know what is wrong with this. I've created a class named MyConnection and this class contains my SQL ConnectionString. What i want is I can call this function ex. Class1 method named Myfunction would be called to my Login Form so calling a connection string would be faster.

```
public static class MyConnection
{
    public static SqlConnection getConnection()
    {                
        string conn = "Data Source=EDGAR-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Project1;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(conn);
        return myConn;    
    }    
}
```

Comment: I am really struggling to understand what your actual question is. Can you clarify?

Comment: What I want to do is call this instantiate this class to my Login form and call this method(getConnection) on that Form. so creating a connection to SQL Server would be faster.

Comment: Did you examine the object to see what is being returned? Also, are you opening the connection in your calling method?

Comment: @Daniel Kelley, it's really hard to understand, but he tries to call that function, not knowing how to instantiate a static class =). Pay attention to the "What i want is I can call this function..." Not everybody of us are guru.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't instantiate the static class. You can call it like this:

```
using (var connection = MyConnection.getConnection())
{
    connection.Open();
    //do whatever you need
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the static class cannot be instantiated, you will have to call like this:

```
private static void OpenSqlConnection(string connectionString)
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
        }
    }
```