# Connection to database

Tags: c#, database

I am trying to create a class that I can use within my application to easily connect to my database and run queries as needed.  I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15793266/calling-an-sql-connection-method-in-c-sharp) post but it is not quite working like I expect.

Here is my class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
//a class that returns a connection to the database
namespace epaCUBE_Utility_Tool
{
    public class epaCUBE_DB
    {

        public static SqlConnection GetConnection()
        {
            string str = "user id=MyUserName;" +
               "password=MyPassword;server=myServer;" +
               "database=myDatabase; " +
               "connection timeout=30";

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
            con.Open();
            return con;
        }            
    }
}
```

and here is how I am trying to use it:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {    
     var connection = epaCUBE_DB.GetConnection();
     connection.Open();    
     SqlDataReader rdr = null;
     string CommandText = "SELECT Field1, Field2 FROM TableName";    
     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(CommandText, connection);    
     rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
     while (rdr.Read())
     {
         this.comboBox1.Items.Add(rdr["Field1"].ToString() + 
  ": " + rdr["Field2"].ToString());
     }
     connection.Close();
 }
```

when I press the button I get an error

InvalidOperationException: The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks,
Leslie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetConnection` calls `Open` for you, but you're calling it again manually after you called `GetConnection`. Call it inside `GetConnection` or outside, but not both places.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is in `GetConnection()` you already open the connection. All these problems came with your static method.
This is not good way to do this, better to create a new instance of `SqlConnection` when you need and dispose after use. The underlying connection pooling will be able to manage the physical connections.

separate your UI with Data access, Here you read the data from database and same time adding items to controls. You need to re-factor the code.

You can have method like below to retrieve data

```
public List<string> GetFields()
{
    List<string> fields = new List<string>();
    string CommandText = "SELECT Field1, Field2 FROM TableName";
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(epaCUBE_DB.GetConnectionString()))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(CommandText, connection))
        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                fields.Add(reader["Field1"].ToString() + ": " + reader["Field2"].ToString());
            }
        }
    }
    return fields;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to open a connection which is already open, this results in exception.
before opening the connection check the connection status and then open the connection

```
cmd.Connection.Open();
```

add the following check/cleanup code:

```
if (cmd.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
{
    cmd.Connection.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I program quite defensively; I expect faults to occur and try to handle that gracefully.

As such..

```
// Define this once in a class and re-use for every connection..
string myConnString = "user id=MyUserName;" +
       "password=MyPassword;server=myServer;" +
       "database=myDatabase; " +
       "connection timeout=30";

    using (SqlConnection mySqlConnection = new SqlConnection(myConnString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand mySQLCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT Field1, Field2 FROM TableName", mySqlConnection) { CommandType = CommandType.Text})
        {
            try
            {
                mySqlConnection.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader rdr = mySQLCommand.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    this.comboBox1.Items.Add(rdr["Field1"].ToString() + ": " + rdr["Field2"].ToString());
                }
            }
            catch (Excecption e)
            {
              // Deal with it as you wish
            }
            mySqlConnection.Close();
         }
     }
```

Comment: thanks I incorporated this into my solution.  I moved the open from my class to inside a Try/catch.